# Append row and cell to table

Tags: jquery, html

I have following code:

```
   function createTable() {
        var $table = $('<table>').css({border:'1px dotted lightgrey'});
        var $row = $('<tr>').css({ height: '20px' });
        var $cell = $('<td>').css({width:'120px'});

        $row.append($cell).append($cell);
        $table.append($row).append($row);
        $('body').append($table);
    }
```

I want to create 2 cell and row inside table but the result is not what I expect, It creates only 1 for each row and cell.

Any advice will be helpful.

Comment: jQuery will take care of that :)

Comment: If we could see the html and rest of the js where the function is being called that would help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clone the cell, else it will be same as relocating the cell when you use .append() second time

```
$row.append($cell).append($cell.clone());
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/DVQ7w/)

Comment: Why using clone instead of `$cell`?

Comment: because you need to created 2 different cells to append it 2 times

Comment: Thanks for your reply, another question, what if I need to add more than 2 columns or rows? Do I need to clone them too??

Answer (score 0):

In extension to Aruns answer,

You can create a method to clone things if you have to add rows or cells multiple times,

```
function CreateClone(obj, count) {
    count = count || 1;
    var clones = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        clones.push(obj.clone());
    }

   return clones;
}
```

And call it like this,

```
var rowClones = CreateClone($('<tr>').css({ height: '20px' }), 5);
var cellClones = CreateClone($('<td>').css({width:'120px'}), 5);
```